# Maximum number of relationship incoming a node in Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, relationship

My graph has a node name **ACTIVE** and then all the node **ACCOUNT** that is activated will have a relationship to **ACTIVE** node.

Assume I have 10 millions node **ACCOUNT** that is activated, so we also have **10 millions** relationship to **ACTIVE** node.

**My question is:** there is any limited for number of relationship incoming a node? (as ACTIVE node above)

And there is any problem about performance if I has to find in graph which node ACCOUNT is activated and which is not activated?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: There is no limit, however this is completely useless to have a single node active and relationships to it. Use an `Active` label instead

Comment: What you are creating here is a super node, which is not advisable. There is not particularly a performance problem if you are starting at a node and then linking to the Active node, but if you are starting at the Active node and linking outwards the performance would be dire. I agree that an ACTIVE label is the way to go, but i would also advise that you read up a bit more on graph design and partitioning, as it seems like you don't really understand fully the implications of super nodes

Comment: @joe Actually the ACTIVE node in my graph just as condition to classify ACCOUNT node. There is no relationship from ACTIVE node to others.
I'm comparing between using ACTIVE label and ACTIVE node. So I have to list all advantages and disadvantages of each one.